# T-sql how to add days when no data in date range

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, addition, days

I need a query and it can only be a select statement, no cte's, functions etc, due to limitations of the reporting solution i am using, to fill days when selecting a date range and there is no values for some of the days, this is to show a trend in a chart and management wants to see all days even if with no data.

note i am using a date range filter "from date" and "to date"

Comment: Create a Calendar table, then JOIN to that.

Comment: can't do the reporting tool only let's saving the one query so it would have to a query that i would put on top and use a union

Comment: The rows **need** to come from somewhere. That will need to be either a function, CTE, or table. You can't "magic" them into existence. If you can't even do a `JOIN` then I suggest its time to find some better reporting software; as that's the problem here. Any basic reporting software would allow you to provide a query as the dataset source, which can include a `JOIN`, and even expressions like a CTE.

Comment: Can it be a `SELECT` from a `VIEW`? If so, then you can do whatever you want in the `VIEW`, like using basic `JOIN` syntax. If not, then I go back to my prior comment; get better reporting software.

Comment: yeah i get you but that is what i can have to work with, unfortunately.

Comment: can't use a view also :(

Comment: Then, if you can't use a `VIEW`, a `JOIN`, a CTE, a subquery, or any *basic* syntax then you can't create the rows. It's as simple as that. You can't magic them, so you will just not be able to report on them and tell your users if the date is missing there is no data. Then start looking at better alternatives to the reporting software. Good luck!

Comment: @Larnu, are you using Power BI as a reporting tool? Because if yes, then Power BI allows working with Views (but no procedures or functions as far as I remember). 
If no, then you basically can't do anything there because SQL syntax to select some data always want's the source (table or function, view, etc.)  to exist.

Comment: I'm not the OP, @ArsenKhachaturyan . I have no idea what they are using, they never told us.

Comment: I am using Stimulsoft with an adaption done by our dev team to accept sql queries

Comment: @AlbertoCaeiro So just to be clear can it only be "select a,b,c from table"? Not for instance "select a.a, b.b from taba a inner join tabb b on a.id=b,id"?
What about [  select dateadd(day,n,'2020-08-01') Dte from (values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4)) d(n)  ] ?

Comment: hi Soren it can make use of all those variations, as long as it starts with a select . Warm Regards, Daniel

Comment: *"as long as it starts with a select"* So *why* can't you use a `JOIN` exactly..? A `JOIN` appears in the `FROM`. Why can't you use a `VIEW` when you would be doing `SELECT ... FROM YOurView`? Why can't you use a function, when a TVF would be referenced in the `FROM`, possibly with an `APPLY`. Only being able to start with `SELECT` is far less limiting that "can't use a function, view, join, or other basic syntax". Your comments are giving conflicting with the limitations you are facing.

Comment: Hi Larnu, the datasource can only start with the select word exactly, i can join or do unions, but i don't have access to create views, functions, etc. Warm Regards, Daniel

Comment: @AlbertoCaeiro then ***why*** did you say "can't do" when you replied to be about using a Calendar Table..? Clearly you *can*.

Comment: please go back and edit your question to reflect the actual restrictions and to improve the grammar so that it is broken into sentences and not just running on, people looking to help you are not likely to try to assemble the actual question by reading through all of the comments

Answer (score 0):

We've had a *lot* of conflicting limitations both in the question and comments on what you can (and can't) do. From *"it can only be a select statement"* and *"no cte's, functions etc"*, to *"can't use a view also"* as well as the far less limiting *"as long as it starts with a select"*. The latter means that, apart from a CTE, you *can* use a `VIEW`, `FUNCTION` and `JOIN`.

As I therefore suggest in my first comment, make a calendar table. In very simple terms:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.CalendarTable (CalendarDate date NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                                CalenderYear AS DATEPART(YEAR, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonth AS DATEPART(MONTH, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderDay AS DATEPART(DAY, CalendarDate) PERSISTED,
                                CalenderMonthName AS DATENAME(MONTH, CalendarDate) PERSISTED); --Some example columns

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2, N N3, N N4),
Dates AS(
    SELECT CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY, T.I, '20000101')) AS CalendarDate
    FROM Tally T)
INSERT INTO dbo.CalendarTable(CalendarDate)
SELECT CalendarDate
FROM Dates;
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.CalendarTable;
```

Then it's as simple as a `JOIN`:

```sql
SELECT CT.CalendarDate,
       {Your Other Columns}
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     JOIN dbo.CalendarTable CT ON YT.StartDate <= CT.CalendarDate
                              AND YT.EndDate >= CT.CalendarDate;
```

Comment: can't create tables, maybe i should have said no objects can be created, has to be all in one go.

Comment: You create the table separately, @AlbertoCaeiro ... Not in the statement the report uses.

Comment: However, please ***stop*** moving the goal posts. You have moved them far too many times at this stage. If you don't know where the goal posts are, then take a step back, find out, and then repost your question with the *real* goal.

Comment: The comments are not for new questions, @AlbertoCaeiro .

Comment: Apologies Larnu, I will do my best not to complicate. Warm Regards, Daniel